# Transfer function of a nonhomogeneous difference equation

Tags: z-transform, transfer-function

Consider the following difference equation:

$y_k=\alpha y_{k-1}+\beta x_k$

The transfer function for this is given by:

$\displaystyle\frac{Y(z)}{X(z)}=\frac{\beta}{1-\alpha z^{-1}} = \frac{\beta}{z-\alpha}$

How does one calculate the transfer function for

$y_k=\alpha y_{k-1}+\beta x_k + \gamma$?

Comment: The context is formulated in another question: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/53540/lti-system-insensitive-to-vertical-shift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last difference equation is not a linear system due to the addition of the constant $\gamma$, therefore it does not have a transfer function.

Comment: However there are ways to [transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2559130) it into a LTI system.